# Changing font from "System" to another preinstalled font?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

According to Apple, iOS comes with several preinstalled fonts:

https://developer.apple.com/fonts/system-fonts/#preinstalled

I would like to use one of them as opposed to the `System` font that I seem to be stuck with. The problem is that the `Attribute` menu of a `Label` or `Button` only allows me to select `System` or `System Italic`.

How can I use another preinstalled font?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should select `Custom` font then you will be giving a list of `Family` where you can select more fonts.

[image]